# How does the address translation between Main Memory and Disk storage work?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, memory-address, virtual-memory, mmu

This question comes up when I learn about virtual memory and memory management.

The following describes what I understand so far:

1. The memory hierarchy, which benefits from locality principle, briefly includes (from top to bottom):

   - register
   - cache (SRAM)
   - main memory (DRAM)
   - disk storage
2. A **page table** provides the **address translation** from **virtual address** to **physical address**

   - The virtual memory provides an abstraction for physical memory
   - **Page**(**Frame**) is the basic unit when **memory management unit (MMU)** manipulates memory between main memory and disk.
   - A process can only understand the addresses inside the virtual address space.

     - Each process has its own virtual address space.
     - Each process has its own page table, and all page tables are maintained by the kernel.
   - a **physical address** describes a **location inside main memory**
   - Translation Lookaside Buffer (TLB) is introduced as a cache-version page table.
3. Cache stores a **tag field** for each cache line to determine its **mapping to main memory**

   - **Cache line** is the basic unit when MMU manipulates memory between main memory and cache.
   - In each cache line, it stores a **tag** field and a **valid bit** to determine what range of physical addresses (e.g. what part of main memory) resides in the cache line.
   - After tranlsating virtual address into physical address with TLB or page table, MMU compares the physical address with cache line tag field, and finds the desired memory content (assuming that cache hits).

---

I believe there's an address translation mechanism between the main memory and the disk for 2 reasons:

1. The main memory is the locality principle result for the disk.
2. To reduce main memory miss rate, the main memory applies the **full associative placement policy**.

However, I only find few material which possiblely relates to the mechanism.
[wiki: frame table data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_table#Frame_table_data) says:

> Frame table data
>
> - The simplest page table systems often maintain a frame table and a page table. The frame table holds information about which frames are mapped.

and [wiki: LBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_block_addressing) says:

> Logical block addressing (LBA) is a common scheme used for specifying the location of blocks of data stored on computer storage devices, generally secondary storage systems such as hard disk drives.

So I guess there's a frame table to store the address translation between physical address and LBA, and MMU would refer to the frame table when page fault occurs.

Please help to point out how does the address translation between Main Memory and Disk storage work.
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

Hard-disk addressing and main memory addressing is done much differently. The CPU doesn't support hard-disk addressing by default. What modern CPUs support is PCI devices that can present an interface to hard-disks like NVME or SATA.

PCI devices have registers that are memory mapped in RAM. The position of these registers is specified in the MCFG which is an ACPI table. ACPI is a convention to represent hardware for software (the os) to be able to determine what is present on the motherboard that it needs to drive. ACPI is also a power management convention which is required for software to even shutdown the computer.

With that said, you can take example on Linux and how it does things to understand how a modern os does to make the link between pages on the hard-disk and the pages in main memory. On the swap management chapter of the kernel.org documentation (https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand014.html), you can read the following:

> ### 11.2  Mapping Page Table Entries to Swap Entries
>
> When a page is swapped out, Linux uses the corresponding PTE to store enough information to locate the page on disk again. Obviously a PTE is not large enough in itself to store precisely where on disk the page is located, but it is more than enough to store an index into the swap_info array and an offset within the swap_map and this is precisely what Linux does.
>
> Each PTE, regardless of architecture, is large enough to store a swp_entry_t which is declared as follows in <linux/shmem_fs.h>
>
> ```
> 16 typedef struct {
> 17     unsigned long val;
> 18 } swp_entry_t;
> ```
>
> Two macros are provided for the translation of PTEs to swap entries and vice versa. They are pte_to_swp_entry() and swp_entry_to_pte() respectively.

You should probably read the link above along with one of my answers on cs.stackexchange.com: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/142525/data-transfer-between-cpu-ram-and-secondary-storage/142553#142553. This will probably provide a fair understanding of what is going on.

Everything is PCI today. You can think of all graphics cards, Intel HD Audio, the AHCI for SATA, the xHCI to drive USB or network cards. That pretty much sums what a current modern computer supports which is audio, USB, SATA, network and graphics. Understanding PCI is thus the key to understand how low level drivers work. The higher level implementation detail is unimportant and varies between os.